# Can draggable widgets be dragged outside of a container into anther container in Kivy(/MD)?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, kivymd

I am using a `ScrollView` in Kivy and KivyMD to display some list items as well as `Scatter`s to display draggable widgets within the `ScrollView`. Is there any way that widgets can be dragged outside of the `ScrollView`? When I try to do so now, they simply disappear from view after dragging outside the bounds of the `ScrollView`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


KV = """

<BGLabel@MDLabel>:
    text: "Label with BG"
    size_hint: 1.0, 1.0
    halign: 'center'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.85,0.85,0.85,0.85
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

MDScreen:

    FloatLayout:

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            do_scroll_y: True
            do_scroll_x: False

            GridLayout:
                size: root.width, root.height
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 1
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: "12sp"
                padding: "12sp"
                
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "Tasks"
                    
                Scatter:
                    id: scatter
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "50sp", "50sp"
                
                    BGLabel:
                        text: "Task 1"
                        size_hint: None, None
                        width: scatter.width
                        height: scatter.height


"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    """Main running class"""

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```